# Create external table with format serde and a extra column - HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying import a txt file to external table whith a extra column in hive, like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bs.tbl_bt(
tp_registro string,
seq string,
num_a string,
dt_chamada string,
hr_chamada string,
num_b string,
pt_interconect string,
dur_rel_chamada string,
dur_tar_chamada string,
tp_servico string,
vl_liq_chamada string,
vl_brt_chamada string,
reserva string,
'${hiveconf:tez.task.operadora}' as operadora string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (input.regex = (.{1})(.{10})(.{21})(.{8})(.{6})(.{20})(.{10})(.{7})(.{7})(.{2})(.{11})(.{11})(.{29}).*)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/gr/Fi/B/${hiveconf:tez.task.operadora}';
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: FAILED: ParseException line 16:3 cannot recognize input near 'as' 'operadora' 'string' in column type

Comment: Thanks. So, why do you need `as operadora`? Last I checked, you only need the column name and type, no other words when creating a table

Comment: I need identify 'operadora' and for that, I use the variable.

Comment: What's wrong with just `'${hiveconf:tez.task.operadora}' string`? Using AS is only possible in select statements, not create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hive DDL does not include AS when defining a column

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] [EXTERNAL] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] [db_name.]table_name    -- (Note: TEMPORARY available in Hive 0.14.0 and later)
 [(col_name data_type [column_constraint_specification] [COMMENT col_comment], ... [constraint_specification])]
```

So, try just

```
'${hiveconf:tez.task.operadora}' STRING
```

Or if you really need the column to always be operadora, then remove the hiveconf variable

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable

Maybe you're mixing up a CTAS statement where you can select a column as another name when creating a table